# IBM MQ Multi-Instance Queues

Tags: replication, ibm-mq

My company uses IBM MQ's Multi-Instance Queues right now.  We would like to replicate those queues to a different Data Center over the WAN for Disaster Recover purposes.  I'm skeptical it will work simply due to all the message traffic and even a slight delay will cause the Queues to fail.

What is the technical reason why this will not work?

Comment: Did you have any further questions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about storage replication?  If so are you planning to use synchronous or asynchronous replication?

Asynch will not cause any delay on the replicating end but there will be some amount of delay before the receiving end receives data depending on network distance.  Your storage team should be able to tell you how many seconds the async replication delay could be.

With synch the data is sent over the network by the replicating end storage array and a confirmation comes back over the network before the the storage array returns to the OS that the write was successful.  To be usable the two arrays have to be with in 6ms of each other.  This type of replication adds a delay to each write equal to the network ms.

MQ application can batch messages into single units of work to improve performance with sync replication is in place, but this will slow down persistent message performance.

Answer (score 1):

Define "Slight delay" in your statement?

- Async replication will cause a delay and RPO will not be zero. Your storage team can advise on RPO value. If that is not acceptable, asynch replication is not an option for you.

  Although it's pragmatic choice from cost and distance standpoint but could cause duplicate or missing transactions.
- For synch replication, the distance in data-centers is limited. (Apart from hit on performance on Primary DC). Check with your storage team on the distance limit.

Comment: +1 Good points Raman, the question is not clear, I understood the delay to be referring to a write side delay not a delay in the RPO, but I can also see it could be in reference to a RPO delay.